# Best Data Model for Invitations?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, data-modeling

I am trying to decide on the best data model to implement Invitation process for a website, that will reduce overhead but also would make sense.

My model will have an InvitationResponses look-up table that will store ResponseID and descriptions like "Accept", "May Be", "Reject". Also, I want to have ability to include user explanation for "May Be" or "Reject" responses.

Therefore, I am trying to decide if I should keep a ResponseID as part of the Invitations table, or have a separate table that will be something like this:

**InvitationsResponses** 
ID
InvitationID
ResponseID
Comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep it all in one table, have a status marker for each event depending on whether it's accepted, rejected, etc... You'll gain better performance with one table than two, especially for something as simple as what you're asking.